# MDX Beginning to Current Date Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, mdx

This is regarding calculating the sum for a set of values starting from the date a measure has entries till the current date.

So far what I could find was the YTD function. This limits the aggregation capability till the current date beginning from the first day of the year. But what my requirement is to start the calculation from the first value, this could be in the last year or may be two years before.

Eg:

Date-----------Value

11/9/2010-----2000

2/10/2011-----500

8/5/2011------1000

With YTD the value is: 1500

What I need is: 3500

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

SUM([Date].[Day].AllMembers, [Measures].[Value])

OR

SUM(OpeningPeriod([Date].[Day]):ClosingPeriod([Date].[Day]), [Measures].[Value]),

where [Date].[Day]  - it's a level DAY of your dimension;
[Measures].[Value] - your measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. When you say SUM([Date].[Day].AllMembers, [Measures].[Value]), does the sum function take in to account all the members of the Date dimension or is it only a subset of the Date dimension which is available in the Fact table (out of which the measure has been derived?)

Comment: It will sum all "values" for your current fact table. For dates which don't have any values you (probably) have 0, so these (blank) values will not be taken into account.
I hope you understand my English :)

Comment: Max, Thanks again. I very well understand your english.

Comment: Are you waiting for another answer? Maybe you can mark my answer as the right one. :)